# Single word (noun) to describe someone who has deep expertise in a specific field and advances that field?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Is there a single word (noun) to describe someone who has deep expertise in an area of specialisation and also advances an academic or engineering field. By "advances", I mean someone who introduces new knowledge (that was previously unknown) into the field or introduces new methods, engineering techniques, etc. into the field. Such a person would also likely have a good breadth of knowledge too but this trait is optional and need not be captured by the word. Is there a noun word that could be used for such a person?

I don't think "inventor" is the right word because this word may not apply to something like mathematics where often times new proofs are said to be *discovered*. In the same way "discoverer" is also not the right word because then it leaves out the inventors.

I thought about "scholar" but it too does not seem right because a scholar can have deep expertise in an area of specialisation without really making any contributions to the field (by adding new knowledge, methods, techniques, etc.)

What is a good noun for what I am looking for?

Comment: How about "paradigm-buster," meaning a person who might spark a scientific revolution (a la Thomas Kuhn's "The Structure of Scientific Revolutions"). Classic example: Copernicus's paradigm about a solar-centered planetary system versus an earth-centered planetary system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call such a person **pioneer**. Per *Collins*

> Someone who is referred to as a *pioneer* in a particular area of activity is one of the first people to be involved in it and develop it.

*Professor Alec Jeffreys, who invented and pioneered DNA tests.*

*Marine biologists have pioneered a technique to grow man-made coral gardens.*

Answer (score 2):

Someone who "introduces new methods, engineering techniques, etc. into the field" is an

**innovator** (n.)

> A person who introduces new methods, ideas, or products [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/innov)

> An innovator is someone who introduces changes and new ideas.
> [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/innovator)

> **innovate** (v.) To make changes: do something in a new way [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/innovator)

---

> Einstein's case as an **innovator** is especially compelling, because
> his ability to objectivize cognition was extremely pronounced....
> [Larisa Shavinina; *The International Handbook on Innovation*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_International_Handbook_on_Innovation/5UFLw_IMc_kC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Einstein%20innovator&pg=PA34&printsec=frontcover)
> (2003)

> The life and work of Newton show a similar scenario, with analogous
> beginnings in adversity. Like Kepler and numerous other radical
> **innovators**, Newton also came from the provinces – from Woolsthorpe, a
> rural community in Lincolnshire. [Anton Blok; *Radical
> **Innovators***](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Radical_Innovators/9nhNDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=newton%20innovator&pg=PA39&printsec=frontcover) (2017)

> [Ralph] Baer, however, was one of those **innovators**, like Edison,
> who believed that filing for patents was a key element of the
> invention process. [Walter Isaacson; *The **Innovators***](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Innovators/H_-hCgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=Baer,%20however,%20was%20one%20of%20those%20innovators,%20like%20Edison,%20who%20believed%20that%20filing%20for%20patents%20) (2014)

> John Newton's “Amazing Grace”... is
> the most sung, most recorded, and most loved hymn in the world.
> ...
> The notion of writing a hymn in order to prepare for a sermon would
> have been alien to most eighteenth- century clergymen, but Newton was
> an ingenious **innovator** in this field of spiritual communication. In the previous two years he had been experimenting with the highly unusual activity (for a Church of England incumbent) of writing "People's Hymns."
> [Jonathan Aitken; *John Newton*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/John_Newton/xqP_YmOAaxUC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=newton%20was%20an%20innovator&pg=PA224&printsec=frontcover) (2007)

Answer (score 0):

A term that was used in the 1980s and 90s in the highest levels of UK scientific research to describe the most innovative scientists and engineers is **prime mover**, sometimes given as the hyphenated word **prime-mover**. Two examples:

[Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/news/2000/jul/22/guardianobituaries1)

> *Rear-Admiral Desmond Callaghan, who has died aged 84, was the prime mover behind the rapid-firing gun that returned triumphantly to favour in the Royal Navy after the Falklands war in 1982*

> [Huddersfield University](https://news-archive.hud.ac.uk/news/archive/2012/asemanticwebprime-mover.php)
>
> *A Semantic Web prime-mover*
>
> *Semantic Web prof primes for third edition of classic text, Grigoris Antoniou  .
>
> When Grigoris Antoniou – now a professor at the University of Huddersfield – first became absorbed in a new field of computer science known as the Semantic Web, he was frustrated that there was no suitable textbook in the subject.  So he wrote it himself.*